# My c socket program spitting out garbage on the command following a successful one, no clue why

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, send

I've tried everything. No idea what's happening with my program. I've written a tcp server and a client. I can issue some commands from the client to the server, they are: ls-local, ls-remote, get filename, put filename (i have not yet implemented put, because I am stuck on get).

Everything works perfectly until I issue the get command. The server.c and client.c files are in different folders. When you issue 'get filename' where filename is the name of the file you want to get, the server checks if the file exists in its current directory, if it does, it sends it to the client.

On the first iteration, this works perfectly. The file is sent to the client and the client creates a copy of said file. However, ANY command besides 'ls-local' results in pure garbage being printed out to the client terminal and I have no idea why. I think it might have to do with me needing to clear a buffer but I tried that and it still didn't work so I'm obviously doing something very wrong.
Here is what happens when I issue a command after get file:
when I issue get filename again, I get a line of garbage and nothing is sent even though the file exists in the server.

If I issue the command ls-remote, this is where it goes crazy printing gibberish non stop to my client terminal.

I've included both files in case you want to test them to see what I mean. Usage is: 'get filename', no single quotes. Remember, it breaks after the first time, works fine the first.  Sorry for the long files, the sending file code is in the method named sendfile, I've tried to organize it so its easy to read.

Need some major help on this, thanks in advance!!

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <dirent.h> 


/**
 * Structure used to contain the type of command: 'get' or 'put'
 * as well as the name of the file
 */
struct command{
    char* type;
    char* filename;
};

void syserr(char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(-1); }

/* function prototypes */
void handleConnection(int);
void sendDirectories(int);
struct command getCommand(char*); 
int fileExists(char*);
void sendFile(char*, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, processId;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, clt_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen;

    switch(argc) {
        case 1:
                    portno = 5555;
                    break;
            case 2 :
                    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
                    break;
         default :
                    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if(sockfd < 0) syserr("can't open socket"); 
    printf("create socket...\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        syserr("can't bind");
    }
    printf("bind socket to port %d...\n", portno);

    listen(sockfd, 5); 

    for(;;) {
        printf("wait on port %d...\n", portno);
        addrlen = sizeof(clt_addr); 
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &addrlen);
        if(newsockfd < 0) syserr("can't accept"); 
        printf("connected to client....\n");

        signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);//prevent zombie process
        processId = fork();
        if(processId < 0){
            // printf("process id < 0, nothing closed\n");
            syserr("ERROR while attempting to fork");
        }
        if(processId == 0){//child process
            // printf("process id == 0, close(sockfd)\n");
            close(sockfd);
            handleConnection(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{//parent process
            // printf("else statement, close(newsockfd)\n");
            close(newsockfd);
        }
    }
    // printf("outside of loop, close(sockfd)\n");
    // close(sockfd); 
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Method that handles the commands received and routes them to the proper methods
 * @param newsockfd the file descriptor created when the connection was accepted
 */
void handleConnection(int newsockfd){
    int n;
    char buffer[256];

    while(1){

        bzero(buffer,256);
        printf("waiting for client's command.....\n");
        n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 255, 0); 
        if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from client"); 
        else buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("SERVER GOT MESSAGE: %s\n", buffer);


        /**
         * exit command
         */
        if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0){
            printf("Ending session with client....\n");
            break;
        }
        /*
        * ls-remote command
         */
        if (strcmp(buffer, "ls-remote") == 0){
            sendDirectories(newsockfd);
        }else{

            struct command userCommand = getCommand(buffer);
            //USER SENDS VALID COMMAND
            if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "invalid") != 0){
                printf("Command %s %s is valid\n", userCommand.type, userCommand.filename);

                /**
                 *  'get' command
                 */
                if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "get") == 0){
                    //File exists
                    if(fileExists(userCommand.filename) == 1){
                        sendFile(userCommand.filename, newsockfd);
                    }
                    //File does not exist
                    else{
                        n = send(newsockfd, "ERROR: FILE DOES NOT EXIST IN REMOTE DIRECTORY", 255, 0);
                        if(n < 0) syserr("Unable to send FILE DOES NOT EXIST ERROR to client"); 
                        printf("Sending FILE DOES NOT EXIST ERROR..\n");
                    }
                }
                /**
                 *  'put' command
                 *  no check needed for 'put' because only possible options at this point are 'get' and 'put'
                 *  since invalid commands are filtered out in getCommand method
                 */
                else{

                }





            }
            //USER SENDS INVALID COMMAND
            else{
                n = send(newsockfd, "INVALID COMMAND: you may only send 'ls-remote' OR  ' get ' or ' put ' followed by a filename", 255, 0);
                if(n < 0) syserr("Unable to send INVALID COMMAND ERROR' to client"); 
                printf("Sending INVALID COMMAND ERROR...\n");
            }
        }

    }
    // printf("in handleConnection, close(sockfd)\n");
    // close(newsockfd); 
}

/**
 * Method that executes when the command 'ls-remote' is received, sends entire file listing in working directory
 * @param  newsockfd the file  descriptor created when the connection was accepted, will be used to send file listing
 */
void sendDirectories(int newsockfd){
    DIR* directory;
    struct dirent *dir;
    directory = opendir(".");
    int n;
    if (directory){
        int count = 0;
        while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
            //ignore current dir and parent dir names
            if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0){
                // // printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                // strcat(dir->d_name, "\n");//concatenates new line char to end of dir name, consider sending without new line and handle new line in client
                // n = send(newsockfd, dir->d_name,255, 0);
                // if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file list to client"); 
                // printf("sending file name: '%s' to client...\n", dir->d_name);
                count++;
            }
        }
        int32_t convCount = htonl(count);
        n = send(newsockfd, &convCount, sizeof(convCount), 0);
        if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file list count"); 
        printf("sending file list count: '%d' to client...\n", count);
        rewinddir(directory);
        while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
            //ignore current dir and parent dir names
            if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0){
                // printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                // strcat(dir->d_name, "\n");//concatenates new line char to end of dir name, consider sending without new line and handle new line in client
                n = send(newsockfd, dir->d_name,255, 0);
                if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file list to client"); 
                printf("sending file name: '%s' to client...\n", dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(directory);
    }
}

/**
 * Method that extracts a valid command from a given string
 * @param  string  the string containing the commands
 * @return   the valid command if found, a command with type 'invalid' if not found
 */
struct command getCommand(char* string){
    char* temp;
    int count;
    struct command userCommand;

    count = 0;
    //Split the string on spaces, if more than one space then # of arguments is > 2, thus invalid command
    temp = strtok(string, " ");
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(count == 0){
            userCommand.type = temp;
        }else if(count == 1){
            userCommand.filename = temp;
        }else{
            userCommand.type = "invalid";
            break;
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        count++;
    }
    //We test count ==1 because this means only one space in string but also only one word because count did not increment again
    //which is still an invalid command
    if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "get") != 0 && strcmp(userCommand.type, "put") != 0 || count == 1){
        userCommand.type = "invalid";
    }
    return userCommand;
}

/**
 * Method that searches server directory for a given file name
 * @param  filename the name of the file to search for
 * @return   1 if the file is found, 0 if not found
 */
int fileExists(char* filename){
    DIR* directory;
    struct dirent *dir;
    directory = opendir(".");
    int n;
    if (directory){
        while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
            //ignore current dir and parent dir names
            if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0){

                if(strcmp(dir->d_name, filename) == 0) {
                    printf("File: '%s' was FOUND!\n", filename);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(directory);
    }
    printf("Sorry file: '%s' was NOT found!\n", filename);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Method that sends the specified file using the file descriptor passed
 * @param filename  the name of the file to be sent
 * @param newsockfd the file descriptor to use to send the file
 */
void sendFile(char* filename, int newsockfd){
    int n, fd;
    struct stat file_stat;
    char buffer[256];
    char* file_buffer;
    char file_chunk[BUFSIZ];

    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

    if(fd < 0){
        n = send(newsockfd, "ERROR: File could not be opened by server....",255, 0);
        if(n < 0) syserr("Error opening file client has requested"); 
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &file_stat) < 0){
        n = send(newsockfd, "ERROR:File stats could not be obtained by server....",255, 0);
        if(n < 0) syserr("Error getting stats of file client has requested"); 
    }

    n = send(newsockfd, "Server found file and successfully opened...",255, 0);
    if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file open confirmation to client"); 
    printf("File found and successfully opened....\n");

    // int data_remaining = file_stat.st_size;
    // int32_t convSize = htonl(data_remaining);
    // n = send(newsockfd, &convSize, sizeof(convSize), 0);
    // if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file size "); 
    // printf("N IS: %d\n", n);
    // printf("Sending file size to client, size is : %d bytes....\n", file_stat.st_size);

    int data_remaining = file_stat.st_size;
    int sent_bytes = 0;
    char str[255];//store file size in string to send, for some reason the above code was sending fine but client could not receive, even though it works perfectly for ls-remote
    sprintf(str, "%d", data_remaining);

    file_buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*data_remaining);

    n = send(newsockfd,str,255, 0);
    if(n < 0) syserr("can't send file size to client..."); 
    printf("Sending file size to client, size is : %d bytes....\n", file_stat.st_size);


    int read_bytes;

    read_bytes = read(fd, file_buffer, data_remaining);
    while((sent_bytes = send(newsockfd, file_buffer, file_stat.st_size, 0)) > 0 && data_remaining > 0){
        data_remaining -= sent_bytes;
        printf("Sent %d bytes of file, %d bytes remain\n", sent_bytes, data_remaining);
    }

    printf("File %s has finished sending....\n", filename);

    close(fd);






}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dirent.h> 


/**
 * Structure used to contain the type of command: 'get' or 'put'
 * as well as the name of the file
 */
struct command{
    char* type;
    char* filename;
};

void syserr(char* msg) { perror(msg); exit(-1); }

/*function prototypes*/
void listDirectories();
struct command getCommand(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd, portno, n;
    int32_t *convCount, *convSize;
    struct hostent* server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    FILE *received_file;

    char buffer[256];

    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <hostname> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(!server){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: no such host: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sockfd < 0) syserr("Error opening socket.");
    printf("create socket...\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)server->h_addr);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        syserr("can't connect to server");
    }
    printf("connection to %s:%s established. Now awaiting commands...\n", argv[1], argv[2]);



    while(1){
        // printf("PLEASE ENTER MESSAGE: ");
        printf("%s:%s> ", argv[1], argv[2]);

        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
        n = strlen(buffer); 
        if(n>0 && buffer[n-1] == '\n'){
            buffer[n-1] = '\0'; 
        }

        if(strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0){
            n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            if(n < 0) syserr("can't send 'exit' command to server");
            printf("send...\n");
            break;
        }else if(strcmp(buffer, "ls-local") == 0){
            listDirectories();
        }else if(strcmp(buffer, "ls-remote") == 0){

            n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");
            printf("send...\n");


            n = recv(sockfd, convCount, sizeof(int32_t), 0);
            if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");

            int fileCount = ntohl(*convCount);
            // printf("CLIENT RECEIVED FILE COUNT: %d\n", fileCount);
            printf("Files at server (%s:%s):\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

            int i = 0;
            while(i < fileCount){
                n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
                if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
                i++;
            }
        }else{

            char cmdCopy[256];
            strcpy(cmdCopy, buffer);
            struct command userCommand = getCommand(cmdCopy);
            if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "invalid") != 0){
                printf("Command %s %s is valid\n", userCommand.type, userCommand.filename);

                /**
                 *  'get' command
                 */
                if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "get") == 0){
                    //Re-append the entire command since
                    n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");
                    printf("send GET request for file: %s\n", userCommand.filename);

                    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
                    if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");
                    else buffer[n] = '\0';

                    if(strcmp(buffer, "ERROR: FILE DOES NOT EXIST IN REMOTE DIRECTORY") != 0 
                        && strcmp(buffer, "ERROR: File could not be opened by server....") != 0
                        && strcmp(buffer, "ERROR:File stats could not be obtained by server....") != 0){

                        printf("%s\n", buffer);

                        //// Not working for some reason, must receive as char*
                        // n = recv(sockfd, convSize, sizeof(int32_t), 0);
                        // printf("N IS: %d\n", n);
                        // if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive file size from server");

                        // int fileSize = ntohl(*convSize);
                        // printf("Size of file: %s to be received is %d\n bytes",buffer, fileSize);
                        // printf("Receiving file: %s \n....", userCommand.filename);

                        n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
                        if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive size from server");
                        else buffer[n] = '\0';

                        int data_remaining = atoi(buffer);
                        printf("file size is %d\n", data_remaining);


                        received_file = fopen(userCommand.filename, "w");
                        if (received_file == NULL){
                            syserr("Failed to open file.");
                        }else{
                            char file_buffer[BUFSIZ];
                            int bytes_received;
                            while((bytes_received = recv(sockfd, file_buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) >0  && data_remaining > 0){
                                fwrite(file_buffer, 1, bytes_received, received_file);
                                    data_remaining -= bytes_received;
                                    printf("Received %d bytes of file, %d bytes remain\n", bytes_received, data_remaining);
                            }

                            printf("File receive complete\n");
                            fclose(received_file);





                        }



                    }else{
                        printf("%s\n", buffer);
                    }

                }
                /**
                 *  'put' command
                 *  no check needed for 'put' because only possible options at this point are 'get' and 'put'
                 *  since invalid commands are filtered out in getCommand method
                 */
                else{
                    // //File exists
                    // if(fileExists(userCommand.filename) == 1){
                    //  sendFile(userCommand.filename, newsockfd);
                    // }
                    // //File does not exist
                    // else{
                    //  printf( "ERROR: FILE DOES NOT EXIST IN LOCAL DIRECTORY\n");
                    // }


                }
            }
            //USER TYPES INVALID COMMAND
            else{
                printf("INVALID COMMAND: you may only send 'ls-remote' OR  ' get ' or ' put ' followed by a filename");
            }

        }

        // n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        // if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");
        // printf("send...\n");

        // while( (n = recv(sockfd , buffer , 255 , 0)) > 0 ){
        //  printf("in while and n is: %d\n", n);
        //      printf("%s", buffer);
        // }
        // if(n < 0){
        //  printf("in if and n is: %d\n", n);
        //  syserr("can't receive from server");
        // }else{
        //  printf("in else and n is: %d\n", n);
        //  buffer[n] = '\0';
        // }
        // printf("in no loop and n is: %d\n", n);

    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

    // printf("connection to %s:%s established. Now awaiting commands...\n", argv[1], argv[2]);


    // do{

    // printf("%s:%s> ", argv[1], argv[2]);
    // fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
    // n = strlen(buffer); 
    // if(n>0 && buffer[n-1] == '\n'){
    //  buffer[n-1] = '\0'; 
    // }

    // n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    // if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");
    // printf("send...\n");

    // n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
    // if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");
    // else buffer[n] = '\0';
    // printf("CLIENT RECEIVED MESSAGE: %s\n", buffer);


    // }while(strcmp(buffer, "exit") != 0);

    // close(sockfd);
    // return 0;


/**
 * Method that extracts a valid command from a given string
 * @param  string  the string containing the commands
 * @return   the valid command if found, a command with type 'invalid' if not found
 */
struct command getCommand(char* string){
    char* temp;
    int count;
    struct command userCommand;

    count = 0;
    //Split the string on spaces, if more than one space then # of arguments is > 2, thus invalid command
    temp = strtok(string, " ");
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(count == 0){
            userCommand.type = temp;
        }else if(count == 1){
            userCommand.filename = temp;
        }else{
            userCommand.type = "invalid";
            break;
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        count++;
    }
    //We test count ==1 because this means only one space in string but also only one word because count did not increment again
    //which is still an invalid command
    if(strcmp(userCommand.type, "get") != 0 && strcmp(userCommand.type, "put") != 0 || count == 1){
        userCommand.type = "invalid";
    }
    return userCommand;
}


/**
 * Method that executes when the command 'ls-local' is received, sends entire file listing in working directory
 */
void listDirectories(){
    DIR* directory;
    struct dirent *dir;
    directory = opendir(".");
    if (directory){
        printf("Files at the client:\n");
        while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
            //ignore current dir and parent dir names
            if(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0){
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(directory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) & `strace`. Understand that TCP is a stream of bytes, not a message protocol: routers, and the network, can split/reassemble packets at will. What works on your machine would work differently elsewhere. You need to buffer on both sides (and deal with *partial* data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your immediate problem, there are two issues:

First in server.c:

```
while((sent_bytes = send(newsockfd, file_buffer, file_stat.st_size, 0)) > 0 && data_remaining > 0){
```

On each send, you're sending `file_stat.st_size` bytes, instead of `data_remaining` bytes.

Also, you should be checking `data_remaining > 0` first.  Since the `&&` operator is a short circuit operator, it won't evaluate the second part unless the first part evaluates to true.  So if you have 0 bytes left to send, it will try to send them anyway.

So the above line should be:

```
while((data_remaining > 0) && ((sent_bytes = send(newsockfd, file_buffer, file_stat.st_size, 0)) > 0)) {
```

Similarly in client.c, you have this:

```
while((bytes_received = recv(sockfd, file_buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) >0  && data_remaining > 0){
```

If you've received the whole file, it will try one more `recv` before it realizes that `data_remaining > 0` is false.  Since the server is done sending, it gets stuck waiting forever.

As before, switch the order of the `&&` operands:

```
while((data_remaining > 0) && ((bytes_received = recv(sockfd, file_buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)){
```

This should at least get you running.

There are further issues in addition to this.  As David Schwartz mentioned, the streaming nature of TCP does not preserve message boundaries.

That means that just because you try to read 255 bytes doesn't mean you'll actually get that many.  Anyplace you expect a message of a particular size, make sure you actually got that many bytes.  If you didn't get enough, keep reading until you do.

Comment: Dude honestly, if I could buy you a beer I would. Thanks a lot for a response that addressed the main purpose of my question, as well as advice on moving forward. Your answer makes complete sense, and it explains exactly why my code was failing. I'll try to clean my code up more and get it up to the proper standards. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3):

```
    printf("SERVER GOT MESSAGE: %s\n", buffer);
```

No, you didn't get a message. You got some bytes. TCP is not a message protocol. If you want to send and receive messages, you have to write code to send and receive messages, which you have not done.

"TCP is a reliable, byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries." Memorize this. Do not write any code that uses TCP until you understand everything in it or your code will be doomed to fail.

Another important point: Do not write any code that uses TCP until you have a specification for the protocol that you are using on top of TCP. Who sends when? Are there timeouts? Which side implements them? How is the connection shut down? Who initiates it? Are there application message boundaries? How are they marked? 
And so on. It really is worth the time to document this in detail. You can look at the specifications for existing protocols that use TCP (such as HTTP, SMTP, IRC, and so on) for examples of what s protocol specification should look like.

Comment: Messages work perfectly fine for me. I'm having issue getting files. I've read a couple of your comments on this matter in other threads during my search for an answer. You seem to go directly into this point of yours while ignoring the actual question and making no actual attempt to help. Unfortunately, I need to use this implementation regardless of whether or not TCP is or isn't a message protocol. I'll definitely take your advice to mind though, when I have the choice of completing this in my own manner. You sound like you know your stuff, id love help from you in solving my actual issue:)

Comment: I see you've edited your answer with additional points. I encourage you to please not downvote my thread so that I may receive help in solving my issue. As to your points, yes I understand there are many aspects of TCP not handled in my code. This my first assignment, I am sure when I learn the caveats you mentioned, I will be tasked with writing a better implementation. Like I said, I have no choice but to implement it this way. Also, the assumption is the server is always running, connections can be terminated by the client sending "exit", no timeouts. This isnt production code, its to learn

Comment: @david-schwartz correctly pointed out a fundamental flaw in your code (one I was also about to point out, but he beat me to it). Don't be quick to dismiss it as a possible root cause of the problem. For example, if the server is executing `ls-remote` and two `send()` buffers get coalesced, then your client's `while(i < fileCount)` receive loop will be unhappy.

Comment: Also, in client.c, `convCount` is an uninitialized pointer. You're passing garbage as the buffer pointer to `recv()`.

Comment: @keithmo Thanks for your replies, can you elaborate on your points? How would two send() buffers coalesce if they are being handled by different processes? Also, what would be the proper way to initialize the pointer your speaking of, perhaps that is the issue. Thanks again for the help, and I'm definitely not dismissing his advice, it's just I would like a better explanation, after all I am here because I don't know something. That's why we ask on this website,specifically, to get answers to questions we do not know. I'd love to learn more, and i will definitely keep trying.

Comment: On the server side `sendDirectories()` goes into a loop reading the dir and calling `send()`. The TCP stacks (on both sides) conspire to break up this data arbitrarily. For example, the server may call `send()` 40 times, each with a 25 byte buffer. On the client side, each `recv()` may return a single byte, or each `recv()` may fill your 255 byte buffer with the data from multiple `send()`s (including fractional parts). If it works for you locally it doesn't mean it's "working fine for you" -- it means you're getting lucky.

Comment: @dalvacoder You're wasting your time trying to fix code that's fundamentally broken. Really. I say this from decades of experience. There is no point in trying to fix a design that is utterly incorrect at its root. Maybe you'll get to the point where it happens to work by luck when you test it.

Comment: @dalvacoder Start by writing a specification. Otherwise, there's no way to tell whether the server or client are doing the right thing because there's no way to know what the "right thing" is.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz, can you suggest a digestible source for learning how to properly implement tcp? My task was to implement and FTP server using tcp. It's a really basic task as its only my first assignment, I realize I must have a fundamentally wrong understanding of it. I thought tcp took care of reliably sending bytes, and simply checking for matching file size would be enough to ensure that it was all sent. Ill read into it more to learn, would love a suggestion for a good source. Nonetheless, I appreciate your advice and comments.

Comment: Looking at example specifications and source code is probably the best way to learn. Find some TCP-using application most similar to what you're interested in and understand an implementation. [This](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) may help introduce you to the basic issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fundamental fallacy in your code noted by David Schwartz, you are committing all the usual mistakes.

```
bzero(buffer,256);
```

Redundant. Remove.

```
n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 255, 0);
if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from client");
else
```

Missing test for `n == 0` and `break` here.

```
    buffer[n] = '\0';
```

Ths is only valid if the data is entirely text. What you should be doing throughout, including the following `printf()`, is using `n` as the exclusive upper bound for what you retrieve out of the buffer.

And as noted, you have no reason to believe this constitutes a complete message, or only one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Indeed the bzero I knew was redundant but it was an attempt to clear the buffer in case that was causing the issue, same goes for the buffer[n] = '\0' line. There may be some remnants of failed attempts to fix my code. Its hard to address your other point as I'm not sure what line in the code you are referring to. Some else statements are incomplete and need to be finished. I wanted to figure out why what i stated in the OP was occurring. I'd love some help figuring out why.